# Text not being retrieved from component in this React application

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react so I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The 'Good Morning Student' greeting isn't being displayed. The error message claims that 't is not defined' but I thought that's what I'm doing in the const.

I'm assuming its something wrong with the syntax but from what I've been reading this is all I can think of it to be.

index.js file

```
module.exports = {
  homepage: {
    'greeting': 'Good Morning Student',
  }
};
```

greeting.js file

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      p: { t }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <p> {t('greeting')} </p>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.PropTypes = {
  Greeting: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Greeting;
```

homepage.js

```
<Greeting />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass prop `p` to your `<Greeting />` component. See this:

```
const obj = { t: {'greeting': 'Good Morning Student'}}

<Greeting p={t} />
```

then you can access it from `props`:

```
const {
    p: { t }
} = this.props;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed in a t function to your Greeting component, that's why it claims to be undefined. In the below code I have imported the data from index.js and passed it into the Greeting component as the greeting prop. Then inside the Greeting component itself I destructure greeting out of the props to use it.

Note that the path to the index file is a guess so edit this to make sure it is pointing to the actual place the file lives in the directory.

hompage.js

```
import data from 'index';

...

<Greeting greeting={data.plp.greeting} />
```

greeting.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      greeting
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <p>{greeting}</p>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.PropTypes = {
  greeting: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Greeting;
```